# mysql_num_rows() is causing the warning

Tags: php, html, mysql

I am having a problem with mysql_num_rows. when i try to login, the following warning occurs:

#### Warning: mysql_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be resource, object given in path/to/userClass.php in line #no.

I searched for that error, and got that, it is caused because of wrong sql query. But i am not sure about that. Please help.

## Userclass.php

### login function

```
$sql = "SELECT id, username FROM `user` WHERE username = '$username' AND hashed_password ='$password'";

$result = mysqli_query( $this->con, $sql );
if ( !$result ) die ("Database query failed" . mysql_error());
else{
    $count = mysql_num_rows( $result );
        if( $count == 1 ){
            $found_user = mysql_fetch_array( $result );
            $_SESSION['user_id'] = $found_user['id'];
            $_SESSION['username'] = $found_user['username'];    
            header( "Location:{$location}" );
        }else{ 
            //username/password combo was not found in the database
            $this->pass_notverified = "Username/password incorrect.";                       
            return;
        }
}
```

## header.php

```
<?php require_once 'class/userClass.php';?>
<?php $obj = new userClass;?> 

<?php 
if( isset( $_POST['login'] ) ){
    $obj->login( $_POST,"home.php" );
}?>
```

Comment: if you are using mysqli function for query then do same for complete code... you cannt mix mysqli and mysql

Comment: You do use `mysqli_real_escape_string` before injecting `$username` and `$password` to your query, don't you? Or, better, use parametrized queries.

Comment: `mysql_*()` API are deprecated. Use either the MySQLi or PDO_MySQL extension instead. [Deprecated mysql_*()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php)

Answer (score 2):

Simple solution:

```
$result = mysqli_query( $this->con, $sql );
```

and

```
$count = mysql_num_rows( $result );
$found_user = mysql_fetch_array( $result );
```

don't work together.
Use the mysqli functions for $count and $found_user (you can find them [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php))

Answer (score 0):

Use `mysqli_num_rows` instead of `mysql_num_rows` and `mysqli_fetch_array` instead of `mysql_fectch_array`.

You cannot use combination of mysql and mysqli functiins